# Update is_online field to true when user logs in

Tags: python, django

Building logic that, when a user logs in would change a boolean field in my Profile model to true and then turn that to false when the user logs out. The problem is I have an api_end point where I can see a list of all users and information related to said users.

If I login as two different users (using different browsers), When I console log their information both users are shown as online:

```
email: "user@gmail.com"
...
is_online: true
...
```

However, when I check the api_end point showing me the list of all users, only 1 user appears to be online (the last user I logged in as).

This is the view related to api_end point to view all users:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.validated_data['new_password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my RegisterSerializer:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
    def validate_password(self, value):
        validate_password(value)
        return value

    def create(self,validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(**profile_data, user=user)
        return user
```

This is my profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/%Y/%m/%d', default='media/placeholder.png', blank=False,
                                    null=False)
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    currently_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_in_session = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @receiver(user_logged_in)
    def got_online(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        user.profile.is_online = True
        user.profile.save()
    @receiver(user_logged_out)
    def got_offline(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        user.profile.is_online = False
        user.profile.save()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=user)
    def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

This is the function that is triggered when a user logs in- this is where I set the `user.profile.is_online` field to true when a user logs in. I assume this is where the problem is coming from?:

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        authenticate_kwargs = {
            self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
            "password": attrs["password"],
        }
        try:
            authenticate_kwargs["request"] = self.context["request"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)
        if not user:
            return {
                'user': 'Username or password is incorrect',
            }
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        # customizing token payload
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['country'] = user.profile.country
        token['city'] = user.profile.city
        token['bio'] = user.profile.bio
        token['photo'] = json.dumps(str(user.profile.profile_pic))

        user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=self.context['request'], user=user)

        if not api_settings.USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE(user):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages["no_active_account"],
                "no_active_account",
            )

        return {
            'refresh': str(token),
            'access': str(token.access_token),
        }
```

Comment: Just so the issue is clear: user #1 logs in and the IS_ONLINE gets updated, then user #2 logs in and the IS_ONLINE is updated. At this point you can see on the admin they are online. But then when you call the API, it shows just 1 online?

Comment: Could you check with the django admin if both users have the `is_online` flag set to `True`?
Or just check it with the python shell `./src/manage.py shell`

Comment: @JanMalte in django admin both users have the `is_online` flag set to `True`

Comment: Could you please add the code wich is showing the users with their `is_online` status? Or am I overseeing something?